# help about macro \uparrowfill

Tags: plain-tex

Is there in plain TeX a macro similar to `\leftarrowfill` but vertically oriented, something like `\uparrowfill`? I know it exists in LaTeX, but I'm interested only in plain TeX.

Comment: Can you add some context where you would be using such a macro?

Comment: @egreg Something like `\vbox to 5in{\hsize=.5in\vbox to2in{\uparrowfill}\vskip1in\vbox to2in{\downarrowfill}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what this should be for, but this could work.

```
\def\downarrowfill{%
  \par
  \begingroup\offinterlineskip
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\downarrow$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox to\wd0{\hss$|$\hss}%
  \copy2
  \kern-3pt
  \leaders\vbox{\kern-2pt\copy2\kern-2pt}\vfill
  \kern-3pt
  \box0
  \endgroup
}
\def\uparrowfill{%
  \par
  \begingroup\offinterlineskip
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\uparrow$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox to\wd0{\hss$|$\hss}%
  \copy0
  \kern-3pt
  \cleaders\vbox{\kern-2pt\copy2\kern-2pt}\vfill
  \kern-3pt
  \box2
  \endgroup
}

\vbox to 3cm{\hsize=1cm\vbox to1cm{\uparrowfill}\vfill\vbox to1cm{\downarrowfill}}

\bye
```

[image]

An alternative way:

```
\def\arrowto#1#2{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{%
    $\left#1%
     \vcenter to #2{}
     \right.
     \kern-\nulldelimiterspace$%
  }%
  \leavevmode\raise\dp0\box0}
\def\uparrowto{\arrowto\uparrow}
\def\downarrowto{\arrowto\downarrow}

a\uparrowto{12pt}a\downarrowto{12pt}a

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: one use: for drawing rectangular commutative diagrams.

Comment: @egreg you've given a spectacular answer, as usual.